# JQUERY Time complexity

Tags: jquery, time-complexity

I tried the following code for updating the value of an element:

**first:**

```
$(this).parent().prev().children(':selected').val();
```

**then:**
I tried with following code:

```
$(this).parent().prev().children('.pgs').val();//`.pgs` is class of `select` drop down
```

**last:**

I also tried with following code:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('.pgs').val();
```

Here, first snippet of code took little more time than the last two snippets. Why did the first snippet show such behavior? How do I find out more about jQuery operations time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) is not a CSS selector the browser understands, it's specificly implemented via [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (the selector engine jQuery's uses), so it goes through a *very* different code path.

`.pgs` however is a perfectly valid CSS selector, something that the browser can optimize heavily, since jQuery can use native cSS selection methods, for instance [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll).

As for more research here, I don't have a great resource for you.  However, the general rule is if it's [a jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) but not [a valid CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) it's going to be slower, since it can't take advantage of several native code paths in the browser.